# How to get Apple Watch to update pages created with WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames: contexts?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I have a WKInterfaceController for a watchkit app, InterfaceController.m. It creates paginated content like this:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *time = @{@"time":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[now timeIntervalSince1970]]};
    NSArray *contexts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:time,time,nil];
    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"page",@"page",nil];
    [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:names contexts:contexts];
}
```

The WKInterfaceController with "page" as the identifier is called PageInterfaceController.m and just displays the time sent by InterfaceController.m

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    [label setText:[context objectForKey:@"time"]];
}
```

This works great the first time it's loaded, but after exiting and relaunching the app, it shows the old times. How can I get the app to go back to InterfaceController.m and update the times?

Yes, I know I could just put the time in PageInterfaceController, but in my real app, the InterfaceController is getting location data and sending it to the pages, even determining the number of pages to be created.

You can download the whole sample project here:

https://github.com/tomkincaid/WatchInterfaceTest

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to use a timer and make it go back to the first interface controller after a certain time. Not ideal as I wish there was a way to have it start from the first interface controller every time the watch app is launched.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    time = [context objectForKey:@"time"];
}

- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    double diff = [now timeIntervalSince1970] - [time doubleValue];
    if (diff > 30) {
        NSArray *contexts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",nil];
        NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"main",nil];
        [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:names contexts:contexts];
    } else {
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",time]];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

awakeWithContext will not be called a second time if the watch keeps the controller loaded, which is probably why it doesn't get updated after the initial load.

Instead, use viewWillActivate in your PageInterfaceController just like you do in your main InterfaceController, like this:

```
- (void)viewWillActivate {
    [super viewWillActivate];
    [label setText:[context objectForKey:@"time"]];
}
```

Comment: viewWillActivate will simply display the same context as before. It needs to go back to the initial InterfaceController to get the new location data.

Comment: Your question is too vague about the problem.  If the problem is that you can't get the original controller to update the data, then stop trying to force it to do that work.  Put a class in the context which can fetch the data for both controllers and use that.

Comment: By the way, I can't imagine why anyone would want to take a chance on helping you if you're going to downvote answers that don't end up being right.  Most people only downvote answers which are just plain bad, not answers that don't end up helping.